# Need to set document mode for specific sites in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility

I'm facing an issue where certain sites in my organization are defaulting to render mode 5 and the page won't load. If I change the document mode to 8 or 9 it works fine.

Is there a way to set the browser to force document mode 9 on site X or Y?

We have admin access to the network. We're using Windows 7 machines.

This is the site: https://cmo.cibc.com

It requires a login which I don't have. The home page works fine but once you're in, that's when we start getting issues.

Comment: Yea we're the admin. We're on Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

If it's going into (IE)5 document mode, then it's going into ["Quirks" mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) because the web page is not reporting it compatibilities..

Suggested possible fix(es):

- If these are local/internal sites, then ensure that IE isn't set to display all Intranet sites in "Compatibility View" - (Tools > compatibility view settings > uncheck "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View".
- Opposite to that, for external sites, try putting the site(s) in question into the [Compatibility View](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/internet-explorer/use-compatibility-view#ie=ie-11-win-7) list.
- Fix the sites to have (proper) doctype and meta tags (this is the real answer, IMO).

Comment: Is there a way to force the mode when putting a site in the Compatibility list, I believe the site automatically renders in compatibility view but in mode 5 which is too low.

Comment: Not that I've ever found -- the render modes are for debugging in the browser, there's no way (except maybe with a 3rd party program, of which I've not heard of one myself) to automatically put IE into one of those mode specifically.

Comment: Really the answer is FIX THE SITES -- things will only get worse are browsers continue to progress.  And I'm not saying this lightly, trust me, I've been fixing work web interfaces for a year now, both internal and those provided by vendors, ensuring they're IE11 ready before bringing the company PC's up to IE11. "Fixing" either by fixing the sites where possible, or applying appropriate GPOs to make IE10/11 agree with them (until fixed properly by vendors).  And there's no way I've ever found to force IE9+ to act like a specific lower browser.

Comment: Related SO question: [Force Internet Explorer 10 Document Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983154/force-internet-explorer-10-document-mode?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the first fix (Compatibility Views) - was really frustrating figuring out why my LIVE site looked good, but my local DEV site that I was working on was all messed up!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to change the document mode type just in the html. IE11 will look for an emie tag and change the document mode to the one specified in the tag. For example if you want IE5, just set the following tag in the header:

```
<emie>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5"/>
</emie>.
```

Here is a link that shows how the document mode is used in IE11:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn321432.aspx

If you look at the flow chat you can see the emie tag and how it is used. Hope this helps.